# How to I run a single sql command from the sqlcmd prompt?

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sqlcmd

In SQL Server, if I want to run a script from the command line, I can do this

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -P $DB_PASS -d $DB_NAME -i myscript.sql
```

Is it possible to run just a single command without a script and get the results?  For instance, if I just wanted to run

```
SELECT 1
```

How would I do that from the command line?

Comment: Try using `sqlcmd /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: You mean '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Password1!' /? "SELECT 1"' ?  This results in a "Sqlcmd: '/?" "SELECT 1': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help" error.

Comment: The OP is clearly using Linux here, @KenWhite , so `/?` won't work. It also seems, for some reason, they haven't added `sqlcmd` to their profile, so they woul need to do `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -?` I do suggest, Dave, you add `sqlcmd` to your bash profile.

Comment: My bad. Use `sqlcmd -?` on Linux.

Comment: And Ken is telling you to inspect the switches available in `sqlcmd` @Dave . There are 2 clearly labeled for your needs.

Comment: Also, if you want to add `sqlcmd` to your bash profile, then you use use `echo "export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin" >> .bashrc` while in your home (`~`) directory.

Comment: I'm a little dense, I'm not following.  This command "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Password1!' -? "SELECT 1"" results in a "Sqlcmd: 'SELECT 1': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help." error.  Entering "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -?" results in a "bash: /usr/work#: No such file or directory" error.

Comment: @Dave ... I gave you exactly what you need to do. `-?` is a common command line switch for "help".

Comment: Be that as it may, entering "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -?" results in a "bash: /usr/work#: No such file or directory" error.  Entering "-?" by itself result in a "bash: -?: command not found" error.  I appreciate your responses.  If it is not possible to do what I'm asking that is good to know as well.

Comment: Then your above command would fail with that error too... Again, why isn't `sqlcmd` in your bash profile... you *should* just be doing `sqlcmd -?` It will tell you ***everything***. if not, use the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15); it's what it's there for.

Comment: If you aren't, however, familiar with the `-?` switch (which is basically on *every* command line command) then you likely want to introduce yourself to command line basics before you start using command line tools. Using the wrong commands can cause more problems than you are trying to solve; especially if you're in an elevated command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the `-q` switch:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U MyUser -P MyPass -d MyDb -q "SELECT 1"
```

Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to:

> run just a single command without a script and get the results

Another possible answer would be to run:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U MyUser -P MyPass -d MyDb -Q "SELECT 1"
```

That is with a capital **-Q.**

This will run the command **and then exit**, allowing you to read the error code result.

The answer above uses lowercase -q, which will run the command but leave the sqlcmd prompt open and running.

Depending on what you want, the case of the -Q/-q argument matters.